# Align Div to top inside td

Tags: html, css

I wish to align the div right under the head. I can't seem to get it to work. (see code & photo).

My Html:

```
          <td>
            <div class="schedule-content">
              <div class="timestamp">
                <h3>00:00 - 00:00</h3>
                <ul>
                  <li>Name1</li>
                  <li>Name2</li>
                  <li>Name3</li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
          </td>
```

My css:

```
#schedule .schedule td .schedule-content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

#schedule .schedule td .timestamp {
  background-color: #fff;
  height: auto;
  width: 95%;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  margin: 0.4rem 0;
}
```

[Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BCoLl.png)

Comment: tell more about the problem

Comment: Add more of your `HTML` and `CSS`. I mean we can see `td` ut not table. No html and css of head

Comment: What is the head in this case?

Answer (score 0):

use align-items: flex-start; on .schedule-content

Comment: I did already try that, it pushes the div to the left, instead of to the top.

Comment: you must also have tried justify-content:flex-start;

Answer (score 0):

Solved it. I added this to the css of the td:

```
td {
  vertical-align: top;
}
```